# Xamarin-Android, setting layout back not working

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, navigation

i have problem with navigating, i can get to the second layout but i can not get back to the first(main) from the second. Even hardware/software back button not working. As far as i know on layout Profil does not work everything, when i try to make button what can change textview on that layout, it does not work too. IDs should be right.

Here is the first activity:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Home);
        Button btnProfil = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnProfil);

        btnProfil.Click += delegate
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(Activity1));
        };
```

Here is the second activity:

```
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Profil);

        Button btnBack = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnBack);
        btnBack.Click += delegate 
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        };
    }
}
```

These formulations works same when they are in same script.

```
Button btnProfil = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnProfil);
btnProfil.Click += delegate { SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Profil); };


Button btnBack = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnBack);
btnBack.Click += delegate { SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Home); } ;
```

Thank you :)

Comment: I did not reproduce your issue, and I think the code is right I write a [demo](https://github.com/mikexxma/AndroidPageNavigationText) for you, it should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i dont know where was a mistake, but i started new project and now it works :)